# How to delete rows in Excel based on criteria using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently building a macro to format a sheet of data as well as to remove inapplicable rows of data. Specifically, I am looking to delete rows where Column L = "ABC" as well as delete rows where Column AA <> "DEF".

So far I have been able to achieve the first objective, but not the second.  The existing code is:

```
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim x, y, z As Integer
Dim StartRow, StopRow As Integer

For x = 0 To LastRow
    If (Range("L1").Offset(x, 0) = "ABC") Then
    Range("L1").Offset(x, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    x = x - 1

End If
```

Answer (score 11):

It is normally much quicker to use AutoFilter rather than loop Ranges

The code below creates a working column, then use a formula to detect delete criteria and then autofilter and delete the result records

The working column puts a formula

`=OR(L1="ABC",AA1<>"DEF")`
into row 1 of the first blank column then copies down as far ar the true used range. Then any TRUE records are quicklly deleted with AutoFilter

```
Sub QuickKill()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
    Set rng1 = Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    Set rng2 = Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    Set rng3 = Range(Cells(rng2.Row, rng1.Column), Cells(1, rng1.Column))
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Rows(1).Insert
    With rng3.Offset(-1, 1).Resize(rng3.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=OR(RC12=""ABC"",RC27<>""DEF"")"
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="TRUE"
        .EntireRow.Delete
        On Error Resume Next
        'in case all rows have been deleted
        .EntireColumn.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: why is autofilter quicker?

Answer (score 8):

Using a **loop**:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(x, 12).Value = "ABC" or Cells(x, 27) <> "DEF" Then
            Rows(x).Delete
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Using **autofilter** (probably faster):

```
Sub test2()
    Range("a1").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="ABC", Operator:=xlOr, _
                           Field:=28, Criteria1:="<>""DEF"""
    'exclude 1st row (titles)
    With Intersect(Range("a1").CurrentRegion, _
                   Range("2:60000")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Rows.Delete
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: Oops, going too fast (I have to, if I want to reply before you do :))

Comment: If you don't want to remove the first row (if you have a header), change `For x = lastRow To 1 Step -1` to `For x = lastRow To 2 Step -1`

Answer (score 1):

Cell with number 12 is "L" and number 27 is "AA"

```
Dim x As Integer

x = 1

Do While x <= ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    If (Cells(x, 12) = "ABC") Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows(x).Delete
    Else
        If (Cells(x, 27) <> "DEF") And (Cells(x, 27) <> "") Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(x).Delete
        Else
        x = x + 1
        End If
    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

    Dim bUnion As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim v1 As Variant

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    v1 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 12), Cells(lastrow, 27)).Value2
    bUnion = False

    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If v1(i, 1) = "ABC" Or v1(i, 16) <> "DEF" Then
            If bUnion Then
                Set r1 = Union(r1, Cells(i, 1))
            Else
                Set r1 = Cells(i, 1)
                bUnion = True
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    r1.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```