# Read first row/column of an Excel spreadsheet with Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

I need to read the data from an Excel spreadsheet like so using Visual Basic.

```
v|123|t
t|123|t
g|123|t
```

I want to read the first column of the spreadsheet and check if it is a V or not. I'm looking to build a script that will delete everything that is not a V, but I am stuck on this.

Comment: Visual Basic (.NET) or VBA?

Comment: @TimWilliams The thing for Excel macros or whatever. Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: "...that will delete everything that is not a V".  Do you mean delete the rows that don't have "V" in column A? Or literally every cell that's not "V"?

Comment: @BruceWayne The first one

Comment: duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648655/how-to-delete-rows-in-excel-based-on-criteria-using-vba http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583637/how-to-delete-rows-in-an-excel-listobject-based-on-criteria-using-vba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick method using AutoFilter. This filters out anything from the first column that isn't "v" then deletes it and removes the filter.

```
Sub vFilter()
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>v"
        On Error Resume Next
        .EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice call - I was going to just loop through Col. A and delete non "v"/"V" rows, but the Filter is probably quicker, and good to learn.

Comment: Does this affect sorting?

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 - I don't think so - since it also removes the filter, it just filters to quickly get the rows without "V", delete those, then remove filter so your data is back.  You should then be able to sort as normal.  Let us know if any issues!

Answer (score 0):

Autofilter is very useful when working with data in tables.

You can select a range of cells (ie the whole table), then click the Filter button found on the Excel Ribbon>Data>Sort&Filter.

This will add drop down lists to each of the top cells in your selection.

You can use these to reduce the list to only show those with a V in the first column.

You can then select all the rows and delete them.

This what the VBA code posted by KFichter is doing.

If you need to just do it once, use autofilters manually.

Harvey