# Delete rows that DON'T meet VBA criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have many worksheets with sequential linear xy data that vary in length. The objective is to delete all rows where x data is not divisible by 50. Below is the generated macro that uses a helper column to search for integers to be deleted.

```
    Sub Divis50()

    Sheets("VERT SCALES").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF((OR((RIGHT(RC[-2],2)=""50""),(RIGHT(RC[-2],2)=""00""))),""YES"",""NO"")"
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C6062")

    'sort filtered results
    Range("C2").Select  
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VERT SCALES").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VERT SCALES").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VERT SCALES").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:C6062")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ' scroll to first no and delete rows
    Rows("123:123").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    'sort "A" back to consecutive numbers
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VERT SCALES").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VERT SCALES").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VERT SCALES").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:C122")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    'delete filtered column
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delete+excel+rows+based+on+criteria

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete rows in Excel based on criteria using VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648655/how-to-delete-rows-in-excel-based-on-criteria-using-vba)

Comment: Most of what I'm finding is deleting rows based on not meeting a discreet value(s) or word(s). I'm looking to keep interval values (i.e. 7000, 7050, 7100,...1,000,000 etc.) and delete all data in between those intervals.  Sorry for the poor explanation.

Comment: Are you looking to delete cells that are not divisible by 50 exactly?

Comment: Still having difficulties. Original post edited with generated macro of my attempt.  Any help is surely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will delete rows that don't equal a whole number when divided by 50

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim FrstRng As Range, Lrw As Long
    Dim UnionRng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Lrw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set FrstRng = Range("A2:A" & Lrw)

    For Each c In FrstRng.Cells
        If Int(c / 50) / (c / 50) <> 1 Then
            If Not UnionRng Is Nothing Then
                Set UnionRng = Union(UnionRng, c)    'adds to the range
            Else
                Set UnionRng = c
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    UnionRng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a helper column that flags your data appropriately. Either through formula or VB.
Then use an Autofilter to select the the flags and then delete.

try here for sample code that will delete filtered data.
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/460513-visual-basic-applications-code-delete-only-rows-filtered.html

Comment: Thanks for that.  My original excel file actually has something similar (YES, NO) using IF OR.  I was interested to see if there was another way to skin the cat.  apologies if you like cats.

Comment: I have added a generated macro code as to my post to how i am getting my output.  I have been attempting to dissect the code given in the link but honestly I am ignorant as to how I would format and insert it within my project correctly.  Any help would be appreciated greatly.