# Remove rows where date older than specified month

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel VBA, how can I remove rows, where a date is between today and a date in the message box.

What I've done so far is just to get the first date of the month from a specified day and year, however what I am trying to do is the following:

Remove all rows where the date in column P is older than the specified month. i.e.
If user selects April, then remove everything where the date in Column P is older than April.

Column P stores the date in the date/time format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

```
Sub Popup()
    Dim Month
    Dim MonthDate
    Dim Year

    Month = Application.InputBox("Enter the number for the month, i.e 5 for May, 11 for November")
    Year = Application.InputBox("Enter full year, i.e. 2016")
    MonthDate = DateSerial(Year, Month, 1)

   With Sheets("Tickets")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
        With Range("p1", Range("p" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<" & MonthDate
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I've tried the above code, however it removes everything with a date before 2016, rather than say April 2016 (when specified)

Comment: you can get the first of the month from cdate(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(dtInput,-1)+1)  you'd just need to use MONTH("P100") = month AND YEAR("P100")=year  no need for 1st of month, just if in month

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648655/how-to-delete-rows-in-excel-based-on-criteria-using-vba

Comment: Is your problem creating a date from the input, so you can compare it the dates in the excel sheet? Or is the problem how to identify the rows identifying the rows (given that you have a date) or how to delete the rows once you have identified them?

Comment: It's on how to delete the rows given the dates :)