# excel vba Delete rows until criteria

Tags: vba, excel, loops, conditional-statements, delete-row

I am new to Excel VBA and could really use some help. I tried searching for a solution throughout the web but was unable to find a similar problem.

I am trying to create a macro that will help to delete Rows based on certain criteria and continue deleting rows until another certain criterion is met.

So for example. In the table below, I would like to delete Rows where Col A = 1 *AND* Col C = 0, and then continue deleting the rows below that row **UNTIL** Col A = 1 and Col C <> 0

```
  A  |  B  |  C
-----|-----|-----
 1   |  TC |  2 
-----|-----|-----
 2   |  TC |  1 
-----|-----|-----
 1   |  TC |  0 
-----|-----|-----
 2   |  TC |  2 
-----|-----|-----
 3   |  TC |  1 
-----|-----|-----
 1   |  TC |  2 
-----|-----|-----
 1   |  TC |  0
-----|-----|-----
 1   |  TC |  1
-----|-----|-----
 2   |  TC |  0
-----|-----|-----
 3   |  TC |  2
```

So the end result of the macro would be:

```
  A  |  B  |  C
-----|-----|-----
 1   |  TC |  2 
-----|-----|-----
 2   |  TC |  1 
-----|-----|-----
 1   |  TC |  2 
-----|-----|-----
 1   |  TC |  1
-----|-----|-----
 2   |  TC |  0
-----|-----|-----
 3   |  TC |  2
```

Ideally, I would like to Loop this again with Deleting Rows where Col A = 2 and Col C = 0 and deleting the rows below that row until Col A = 2 and Col C <> 0.

Below is the macro that I Came up with. Open to all suggestions and eager to learn.

```
Sub deleterow()

Range("C2").Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) = "1" And ActiveCell.Value <> "0"
If ActiveCell.Value = "0" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) = "1" Then
Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Looking forward to hearing back!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your loop stops on the first line, because the criteria is met. So the code below loops from first row to last filled row to search for the criterias.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'Set the first worksheet to work
Dim n As Long, i As Long
Dim rng As Range, new_rng As Range

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'lastrow number
For n = 1 To 2 'Criteria is Col A = 1 To 2
    For i = 1 To lastrow 'Loop from 1 to last row
        If ws.Cells(i, 1) = n And ws.Cells(i, 3) = 0 Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = ws.Range("A" & i) 'Set first Range so Union won't give an error
            Set new_rng = ws.Range("A" & i)
            Set rng = Union(rng, new_rng) 'create a non contiguous range to delete
        End If
    Next i
Next n

rng.EntireRow.Delete
```

> Note that if the Sheet is large, it isn't the optimal method. There are best ways to improve the code performance. A loop was used, because it was the method tried by the OP.

Another way is to filter for multicriteria and delete the shown rows.

Comment: Apologies in advance as I am very new at this. I tried to apply the above code, but it does not seem to work. I am reviewing your code and I'm not sure I understand. I think I understand the concept of the code, but I cannot grasp certain lines of it. Why is it "if rng is nothing then set"..? should it not be "if rng is not nothing then set"? And I do not understand the line "rng = Union(rng,new_rng)". how is it possible to have rng equal a Union of itself and a new rng?

Comment: Also, I am not sure how a filter and delete method would work for this particular problem. Because macro needs to continue deleting until a criterion is met. However, I am open to any solution as long as it works.

Comment: The Union is used to create a non contiguous range, like `Range("B1:B5","C42:C65","Z300")`, so you can delete everything using delete once. Because the delete action is slow, so if you delete just once, it can optimize the time it takes to make those actions. And `If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = ws.Range("A" & i)` is used to use the Union, because if there aren't 2 ranges, Union gives an error. So for the first range (when rng is empty or nothing), you set `rng=new_rng=ws.Range("A" & i)`

Comment: And refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7649192/7690982) to learn how to dele with autofilter and with loop